# Numbering text files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have some text files placed in the same folder as a batch file. I need the batch file to echo the filenames without its extention line by line with a numbering. It has to be in alphabetical order. Also, it needs to store the file name into a variable fruitx where x is the number of its numbering. For example...

If I have three files in the folder:

Banana.txt
Cherry.txt
Apple.txt

I need the batch file to echo:

1) Apple

2) Banana

3) Cherry

Then, I need the variable %fruit1% be "Apple", %fruit2% be "Banana" and %fruit3% be "Cherry".

```
    set x=0
    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    set /a x=x+1&echo %x%^) %%~nI&set fruit%x%=%%~nI)
    echo %x%
```

Here is my code. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why. It echos 0 for each of the numberings instead.

Sorry if this sounds confusing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the cmd parser reads a line or a block of lines (the code inside the parenthesis), all variable reads are replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the code. If the execution of the code in the block changes the value of the variable, this value can not be seen from inside the same block, as the read operation on the variable does not exist, as it was replaced with the value in the variable.

This same behaviour is seen in lines where several commands are concatenated with `&`. The line is fully parsed and then executed. If the first commands change the value of a variable, the later commands can not use this changed value because the read operation replace.

To solve it, you need to enable delayed expansion, and, where needed, change the syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation needs to be delayed until the execution of the command.

In your case, the problematic variable is `x`, that changes its value inside the loop and needs this value inside the same loop

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "x=0"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /on *.txt 2^>nul') do (
        set /a "x+=1"
        echo !x!^) %%~na
        set "fruit!x!=%%~na"
    )
    echo(---------------------------
    set fruit
```

Also, an alternative approach without delayed expansion can be to filter the generated list of files with `findstr` to generate the number for each element

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /on *.txt 2^>nul ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
        echo %%a^) %%~nb
        set "fruit%%a=%%~nb"
    )
    echo(---------------------------
    set fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:n *.txt') do (
    set /a counter=counter+1
    echo !counter! ^) %%~na
    set "fruit!counter!=%%~na"
)

echo listing fruits
set fruit
```