# My batch script only works the second time

Tags: git, batch-file

I have written a batch script that commits my GIT repository from a file. This script first asks if I am sure I want to commit the staged changes then looks for the changelog file and stops if it is not found, if it is found, the commit is done, a backup of the changelog is created and the changelog is emptied.

Now my issue is that the first time I call it in a command prompt it asks me if I really want to commit, and whatever I answer it stops right after that (well not quite true, it DOES execute the `PAUSE` command, without writing anything else, just as if I didn't type y or Y). All the times I run it in the SAME command prompt after that first time, it works as expected. Now that never breaks anything, but having to run it twice every time is a bit useless and most probably is a bug and avoidable, so any help is appreciated ;)

Here is my script

```
@ECHO OFF
set displayErr=0
set /p isOk="Do you really want to commit the staged work? (Y/N)"

if "%isOk%"=="y" set isOk=Y

if "%isOk%"=="Y" (
    echo "Looking for changelog"
    set filter="%~dp0\..\changelog\changelog.txt"
    for %%A in (%filter%) do if %%~zA==0 (
        echo."%%A" is empty
    ) else (
        git commit -F "%%A"

        if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            echo Cancelling. "git commit" returned an error code...
        ) else (
            copy "%%A" "%%A.backup"
            copy /y NUL "%%A"
        )
    )
) else (
    echo "Cancelling..."
)

PAUSE
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032907/2861476) why it happens.

You can enable delayed expansion

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion                    <<<<<< HERE
    .....
    if /i "%isOk%"=="Y" (
        echo "Looking for changelog"
        set "filter=%~dp0\..\changelog\changelog.txt"
        for %%A in ("!filter!") do if %%~zA==0 (       <<<<<< AND HERE
    ....
```

or, easier option, move the definition of `filter` variable out of the `if` command.

```
....
set "filter=%~dp0\..\changelog\changelog.txt"

set /p "isOk=Do you really want to commit the staged work? (Y/N)"
if /i "%isOk%"=="Y" (
    echo "Looking for changelog"
    for %%A in ("%filter%") do if %%~zA==0 (
....
```

Why did it work on the second run? The first time you execute the batch, as the changed value is not seen the process fails, but as you are not using `setlocal` to protect the environment from changes, the variable is defined and the value stored into it, so, in the second run this previous value is used and the code works.

Comment: Funniest part is I actually heard about the delayed expansion when doing research to write this script :P And still I got caught, well thanks a lot, that's really helpful ! Well by the way, from what I understand, does that mean that my script is late by one execution about the decision I take? Like if I say `n` the first time, the second time I execute it, if I answer `y` it will act as a `n`, and on the third execution, no matter what, the script will think it's a `y` and so on?

Comment: @DevilBlackDeath, no, your problem is `filter`. Its value is asigned inside a block, and can not be retrieved inside the same block without delayed expansion. In the second run you have the same problem, you assign a value and this value is not seen, BUT as the previous value (the assigned in the previous run) has not been cleared, it is used. It seems to work, but if the code is executed the second time from a different folder, the wrong reference will be used.

Comment: Oh ok ! Well thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Not too familiar with batch scripts, write them once in a while when I need some feature though. Unfortunately in my computer science school, they didn't (and probably won't for the next students) teach us batch scripting, only bash scripting. Well I think batch scripts are quite powerful too, just they have a less intuitive syntax