# If and Else statements

Tags: batch-file

i having problems with if and else statements in script batch.
Here my scripts:

**Main**

```
@echo on

:varIniciais
set dia=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~-4%
set hora=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
cd C:\Script\Apri\SITDF\2.4.12
set local=%cd%
set /a cont=1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:capturaMaquinas
for /f "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (maquina.txt) do (
    :verificaContador
    set estacao=%%i
    if %cont% LEQ 30 (
        call testaRede.bat
        if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
            call copiaScript.bat
            if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
                call permissaoScript.bat
                if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
                    echo ---------------------------------- >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                    echo %estacao% >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                    echo Copia realizado com sucesso >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                )else(
                    echo ---------------------------------- >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                    echo %estacao% >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                    echo Erro ao liberar permissão no script >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                )
            )else(
                echo ---------------------------------- >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                echo %estacao% >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
                echo Erro ao realizar a copia do script >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
            )
        )else(
            echo ---------------------------------- >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
            echo %estacao% >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
            echo Estação não está respondendo na rede >> "%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"
        )
        set /a cont+=1
    )else(
        sleep 12
        set /a cont=1
        goto verificaContador
    )
)

endlocal
```

Im brazilian and the text of my code is in portuguese. 
The error is occurring in one "else", I believe the problem is syntax.
Thanks, and sorry for the bad english.

---

MC ND or someone,

When will i get this loop?

```
if not defined errors call copiaScript.bat || (
            >> "%logFile%" echo ----------------------------------
            >> "%logFile%" echo !estacao! 
            >> "%logFile%" echo Erro ao realizar a copia do script
            set "errors=1"
        )
```

**copiaScript.bat**

```
@echo on

:varIniciais
set estacao=%1
cd C:\Script\Apri\SITDF\2.4.12

:copiaScript
pscp -pw estacaolivredebian Script_Geral_v3.1.sh caixa@%estacao%:/home/caixa

if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    exit /b 0
) else (
    exit /b 1
)
```

Comment: What error are you getting btw?

Comment: C:\Script\Apri\SITDF\2.4.12>setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
else( foi inesperado neste momento.
C:\Script\Apri\SITDF\2.4.12>                            )else(

Translating...

else (was unexpected at this time.

Comment: When the loop is called? if `errors` is not defined (no previous code has set it to 1), `copiascript.bat` is called. The syntax `command && code on sucess || code on failure` is somehow equivalent to `if not errorlevel 1 ( ) else ( )` . In this case, the code after the `||` is called on failure (errorlevel is not 0) of the previous command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with: you can not use `goto` to jump to a point inside a `for` loop, the logic of the counter is wrong (skips one machine), the delayed expansion of variables (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032907/2861476)) and the syntax of the `else` (spaces are needed).

This is not tested code, but may be used as a starting point

```
@echo on

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    set "dia=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~-4%"
    set "hora=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
    cd "C:\Script\Apri\SITDF\2.4.12"
    set "local=%cd%"
    set "logFile=%local%\Logs\monitora %dia% %hora%.log"

    set /a "cont=0"

    for /f "tokens=1" %%i in (maquina.txt) do (

        set "estacao=%%i"
        set "errors="

        call testaRede.bat || (
            >> "%logFile%" echo ---------------------------------- 
            >> "%logFile%" echo !estacao! 
            >> "%logFile%" echo Estação não está respondendo na rede 
            set "errors=1"
        )

        if not defined errors call copiaScript.bat || (
            >> "%logFile%" echo ----------------------------------
            >> "%logFile%" echo !estacao! 
            >> "%logFile%" echo Erro ao realizar a copia do script
            set "errors=1"
        )

        if not defined errors call permissaoScript.bat || (
            >> "%logFile%" echo ---------------------------------- 
            >> "%logFile%" echo !estacao!
            >> "%logFile%" echo Erro ao liberar permissão no script
            set "errors=1"
        )

        if not defined errors (
            >> "%logFile%" echo ---------------------------------- 
            >> "%logFile%" echo !estacao! 
            >> "%logFile%" echo Copia realizado com sucesso
        ) else (
            echo !estacao! FAILED
        )

        set /a "cont+=1"
        if !cont! GEQ 30 (
            sleep 12
            set "cont=0"
        )

    )

    endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

In `copiaScript.bat` you have this line but your code calling this batch file does not pass a `%1` parameter - so this variable will always be empty.

```
set estacao=%1
```