# Batch file to repeat a program process

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im not entirely familiar with command line scripting. I am trying to create a batch file to read in a txt file, apply a format which converts the file from a report into table and then export the file as spreadsheet.

I can get the script to work for an individual file however if I try to run multiple files through a loop nothing happens. It launches the program goes through each script line but again doesn't do anything. It doesn't set the path. No crashes. Where as where I take the script out of the loop and apply it to a single file it works fine. Any suggestions?

```
SET monarch_bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Datawatch\Monarch\Program\Monarch.exe"

 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\*.txt"') do (

    echo File directory : %%i

    SET infilename=/Rpt: "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\%%i.txt" 
    echo ####### In file name:%infilename%

    SET model_file=/mod:"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\InvoiceSummary.xmod" 
    echo ####### Model: %model_file%

    SET outfilename=/exp:"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\OUTPUT.xlsx" 
    echo ####### Out file name:%outfilename%

    SET mode=/expfileopt:append /T
    echo ####### File: %%i
    %monarch_bin%%infilename%%model_file%%outfilename%%mode%
pause
)
```

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25032907/2861476).

Comment: Hi MC nd, I have tried to implement the solution provided but either I have the syntax wrong or I just don't really understand.

Comment: Sorry, i mean the origin of the problem in the other question is the same: changes in your variables are not seen inside the block that changes the variable. I've included a modification of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed expansion problems (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032907/2861476))

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET monarch_bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Datawatch\Monarch\Program\Monarch.exe"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\*.txt"') do (

    echo File directory : %%i

    SET infilename=/Rpt:"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\%%i.txt" 
    echo ####### In file name: !infilename!

    SET model_file=/mod:"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\InvoiceSummary.xmod" 
    echo ####### Model: !model_file!

    SET outfilename=/exp:"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input\OUTPUT.xlsx" 
    echo ####### Out file name: !outfilename!

    SET mode=/expfileopt:append /T
    echo ####### File: %%i

    %monarch_bin% !infilename! !model_file! !outfilename! !mode!

)
```

If a variable value is changed inside a block of code you need delayed expansion to retrieve the changed value inside the same block of code.

But, this can be written as

```
set "monarch_bin=C:\Program Files (x86)\Datawatch\Monarch\Program\Monarch.exe"
set "inputFolder=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample Monarach Input"

for %%i in ("%inputFolder%\*.txt") do (
    "%monarch_bin%" ^
    /Rpt:"%%~fi" ^
    /mod:"%%~dpiInvoiceSummary.xmod" ^
    /exp:"%%~dpioutput.xlsx" ^
    /expfileopt:append /T
)
```

Where the `for` loop will iterate over the list of the `.txt` files, and `%%i` will hold a reference to the file so, `%%~fi` is the full path to the file and `%%~dpi` is the drive and path where the file is stored.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I had something similar to above but it was space characters in the file names that were causing an issue.